# Why is my reactioncollector working only for me

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am currently trying to create a bot that adds a verification system that adds a specific role to the user upon reacting. This works, but when another user tries it does not work. Even removing the reaction upon reacting only works for me. Bear in mind, I have only just got back into the discord bot game so I am a little rusty. Below is the snippet of code, it just does not work for other users, but does for me. This is written in NodeJS - discord.js

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + 'verify')) {
        message.delete()
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(config.embedcolor)
    .setTitle('✅ Verification Board ✅')
  .setFooter('Copyright © 2020 History GFX', 'https://i.imgur.com/1HkdOVY.png')
    .setDescription('')
message.channel.send(embed).then(async message => {
    await message.react('✅');
    const collector = message.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) => user !== client.user)
collector.on("collect", (reactionCollect, user) => {
    if(reactionCollect.emoji.name === "✅"){
      let verify = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === " Client");
      message.guild.member(user).roles.add(verify);
      reactionCollect.users.remove(user);
      }
    });
})
        };
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you using intents and if you are are you subscribed to `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`?

Comment: Thank you :) and I don't believe so, this code I made a few months ago which worked flawlessly. Now I  have come back to use it, it doesn't work.